# Remove contour checkbox in jquery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I got this, but I do not want the yellow outline. How can I do?

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
 <div class="ui-block-a">
              <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e" style="height:50px">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
                     <label for="checkbox-1"></label>
               </div>
```

Comment: you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9HUSJ/

Comment: No, I want the yellow box with a checkbox normal to the center. With jquery Mobile is wrong, maybe I have to use something else, but what?

Comment: It's meant to be this way because it accommodates text. Unless you dont want a text inside, you need to override its style.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can I have an example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9HUSJ/ check this

Comment: It 's definitely better than before. You can put at the center of the cell?

Comment: check the same link above.

Comment: hombre, tienes que practicar CSS ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31770/discussion-between-conicadegenere-and-omar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override checkbox style in three steps.

Position of checkbox itself, which lays behind the visual checkbox. I have added `div.-ui-bar` before each overridden style in order not to specific and to keep original styles elsewhere.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9HUSJ/)**

```
div.ui-bar input {
 left: 10px !important
}
```

Width of label

```
div.ui-bar label {
 width: 27px !important
}
```

Position of visual checkbox

```
div.ui-bar .ui-checkbox .ui-btn-icon-left .ui-icon {
 left: 5px !important
}
```